# Can someone explain me this javascript object "copy" behavior

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code (I am using the jQquery libary):

```
var obj = {};
var objstring = '{"one":"one","two":"two","three":"three"}'

// first console output
console.log(objstring);

var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(objstring);

// second console output
console.log(jsonobj);

obj.key = jsonobj;
obj.key.test = "why does this affect jsonobj? (even in the second console output)";

// third console output
console.log(jsonobj);
```

My Question:
When I do obj.key = jsonobj and I change values in the new obj.key. Why do values in jsonobj then also change? And how would I avoid that? (I want a new "copy" of jsonobj).

I made this test case: http://jsfiddle.net/WSgVz/

Comment: Excellently-formed question and testcase. It's incredibly sad that this is so rare nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the object is not copied. The `obj.key` property will only contain a reference to the object, so when you assign something to `obj.key.test` the effect is the same as assigning it to `jsonobj.test`.

You can use the jQuery method [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to create a copy:

```
obj.key = $.extend({}, jsonobj);
```

This will copy the values into the newly created object (`{}`).

Comment: Also worth noting you'll need `$.extend(true, {}, jsonobj)` for deep copy (as opposed to shallow one-level copy).

Comment: @Domenic: Good point, that's good to know for more complex object structures.

Answer (score 5):

I want to address a small piece of what is going on here, since others have done so well addressing the larger issues of JavaScript object references:

```
// second console output
console.log(jsonobj);

obj.key = jsonobj;
obj.key.test = "why does this affect jsonobj? (even in the second console output)";
```

This is the result of a [documented WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801), that `console.log` statements do not output the object at the time of calling `console.log`, but instead some time later.

Comment: I tried to make it much clearer what I was getting at this time around, so please explain any -1 votes...

Comment: oh ok, this only contributed to my former false understanding of how javascript handles object copying/delegation. thank you for pointing this out ;).

Comment: Changed my -1 to a +1. At the time of my vote you didn't have as detailed of an answer. Now I have egg on my face.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you do `obj.key = jsonobj`, there isn't some new, copied object in `obj.key`; it's just a reference to the `jsonobj` that already exists. So changes to `obj.key` will also change `jsonobj`, because they're actually the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there *is* no copying going on -- there is only one object, which is [*referenced*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29) by various variables and properties. When you do `obj.key = jsonobj`, you are merely copying the reference to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

All objects in JavaScript are copied by reference, meaning:

```
var x = {};
var y = x;
x.foo = 22; // y.foo also = 22 since y and x are the same object
```

If you want `obj.key != jsonobj`, you need to clone the object.  By creating a new object:

```
obj.key = $.parseJSON(objstring);
```

or using jQuery to clone the existing one:

```
obj.key = $.extend({}, jsonobj);
```

Comment: But I don't seem to find the answer behind the output of the second log..........

Comment: the 2nd log statement is just wrong, per Domenic's answer.  If you want a valid console.log: `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonobj))`